# An approximation for path integral kernels

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral

The kernel in the path integral formulation for a one dimensional
system is given by
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:kernel1}
  K(x_b, t_b; x_a, t_a) =
  \lim_{N \to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{m}{2\pi i \epsilon}}^N
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cdots \int_{-\infty}^\infty
  \exp\left( i S_N \right)
  dx_1 \cdots dx_{N-1}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
  S_N = \epsilon \sum_{n=1}^N \left( \frac{m}{2}
  \left( \frac{x_n - x_{n-1}}{\epsilon} \right)^2 -
  V(x_n,t_n) \right)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
  \epsilon = \frac{t_b-t_a}{N} .
\end{equation}
We assume that the potential $V$ does not depend on time. We
approximate the kernel by setting $N=2$ and we get
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:kernel2}
  K_2(x_b, x_a ; \epsilon) :=
  \frac{m}{2\pi i \epsilon}
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left( i S_2 \right) dx_1
\end{equation}
We have
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:kernel3}
  K_2(x_b, x_a ; \epsilon) =  \frac{m}{2\pi i \epsilon} I
\end{equation}
where
\begin{eqnarray}
  I & := & \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(i S_2) dx_1 \\
  \nonumber
  & = & \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left( i \epsilon \left(\frac{m}{2}
  \left( \frac{x_1-x_a}{\epsilon} \right)^2 - V(x_1)
  + \frac{m}{2} \left( \frac{x_b-x_1}{\epsilon} \right)^2 - V(x_b)
  \right) \right) dx_1 \\
  & = &
  \nonumber
  \exp \left( i \left( \frac{m}{2\epsilon}
  \left( x_b^2 + x_a^2 \right) - \epsilon V(x_b) \right) \right) \\
  & &
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left( i \left( \frac{m}{\epsilon} x_1^2 -
  \epsilon V(x_1) \right) \right)
  \exp\left( -i \frac{m}{\epsilon} (x_b + x_a) x_1 \right) dx_1 \\
  & = &
  \sqrt{2 \pi}
  \exp \left( i \left( \frac{m}{2\epsilon}
  \left( x_b^2 + x_a^2 \right) - \epsilon V(x_b) \right) \right)
  \hat{h}\left( \frac{m}{\epsilon} (x_b + x_a) \right)
\end{eqnarray}
and
\begin{equation}
  h(x_1) := \exp\left( i \left( \frac{m}{\epsilon} x_1^2 -
  \epsilon V(x_1) \right) \right)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:kernel4}
  K_2(x_b, x_a ; \epsilon) =
  \frac{m}{2\pi i \epsilon}
  \sqrt{2 \pi}
  \exp \left( i \left( \frac{m}{2\epsilon}
  \left( x_b^2 + x_a^2 \right) - \epsilon V(x_b) \right) \right)
  \hat{h}\left( \frac{m}{\epsilon} (x_b + x_a) \right)  \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Has this kind of approximation been used before?